PID controller too slow even P is changed
I had a extech 48VFL PID controller. The settings are all in default values except P, I, and D. I set them to be 100, 3600, and 60. Just random numbers. I found it's heating super slow, it has been half an hour and the temperature has not reached 40C from room temp. I increased P to 200 and it does not make any difference. Why this is happening? Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Show us the system diagram and what you are controlling. What kind of output does the controller have? (Voltage, current, ???) What does the device being controlled accept? What should the variable be at 100% power? What is the controller producing? I really don't have a working crystal ball.

Check if the output is at 100% — if so then you have insufficient control authority.
I don’t know why you would set PID to random numbers. Use the auto tune function and let it figure out the appropriate PID values.
But if your heater is inadequate then the controller cannot do any more than call for 100% heat (and if it cannot reach the set point, then the AT will never reach completion).
